# Giving error IOException java.net.ConnectionExeption.connection denied

Tags: java, android

Giving error  IOException java.net.ConnectionExeption.connection denied`enter code here`

public class Client extends AsyncTask {

```
String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String response = "";
TextView textResponse;

Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    this.textResponse = textResponse;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        /*
         * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
         */
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    textResponse.setText(response);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

```
getting error of connection refuse can any one help me
```

from this situation i an My Ip is 10.0.2.15 and port is 5000
And in server side connection is up to ready for connection

Comment: `My Ip is 10.0.2.15`. Your ip is irrelevant. What is the ip of the server? And what of the client?

Comment: same ip for server and client

Comment: So client and server run on the same device? On an Android device? You should tell your setup! If they run on the same device you should use 127.0.0.1.

Comment: NO i am using two diffrent emulator to run client and server and the ip of both the emulator is 10.0.2.15 then also it is not connecting

Comment: any one can hepl me answer

Comment: Well if the ip of both emulators is the same then how would that ip be usefull to connect to the other one? Impossible situation of course.

Comment: Using two emulators in this way is impossible. And you should have told from the start that you work with two emulators.